React state cannot be updated without hard refresh after switching to a route in Next js
I am using Next 14.1.4 and React 18.
It seems like it's impossible to update state without a hard refresh. State's value is apparently cached client-side and nothing helps to get rid of it.
During building a client component with an infinite scroll I realized that everything works fine if a user scrolls till the end and then switches to a route. But if the user decides to switch halfway to a different route, its state is "stuck".
I tried rewriting the component with useState and setting the initial data inside the useEffect hook, or using router.refresh() there, so whenever component renders for the first time, it gets the initial data, but it didn't help.
Update: this is the code: (a component with infinite scroll)
`
'use client'
import Link from 'next/link';

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

let chunk = {
    number: 1
}

export default function TodoList() {

// initialization of basic state data

const initialTodos: { id: number, text: string }[] = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    initialTodos.push({
        id: i,
        text: "some fetched todos #" + (i + 1)
    });
}

const [data, setState] = useState(initialTodos);

let onScroll = (event: Event) => {

// this event handler updates the state with random data after user scrolls down a bit 

    let vp = event.target as VisualViewport;
// An item has 148 px height. A block has 30 items
    let halfOfTheBlockHeight = (148 * 30) / 2; //const
// multiplying block's height by the number of chunks or blocks
    let totalHeightOfTheBlock = 148 * 30 * chunk.number;
// calculating the middle part of the last block
    let middleOfTheBlockPageTop = totalHeightOfTheBlock - halfOfTheBlockheight;

// if the viewport's top offset is greater than the middle part of the data block top offset, then remove this handler and fetch new data. 
    if (vp.pageTop > middleOfTheBlockPageTop) {

// increment chunk's number so user needs to scroll lower to get a new data each time new data is fetched

        chunk.number = chunk.number + 1;
        window.visualViewport?.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll, false);
        let length = data.length;
        let arr = [...data];
        for (let i = length; i < length + 30; i++) {
            arr.push({ id: i + 1, text: 'random' + i });
        }
        setState(arr);
    }
};
useEffect(() => {
//reset chunk.number for the first render
    chunk.number = 1;
    window.visualViewport?.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll, false);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
// add a new event hanlder each time new data is fetched
    window.visualViewport?.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll, false);
}, [data]);


return (
    <>
        <Link href="/"> Base Route </Link>
        <Link href="/example"> Another Route </Link>
        <ul>
            {data.map((item: { id: number, text: string }) => (
                <li style={{ height: 148 }} key={item.id}>
                    {item.text}
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    </>
);

}
`
Update: cleaned code.
Update: added some comments.
All I want is continuation of data fetching upon scrolling after navigation.

Can you share some code with us so can have a better understanding of the problem?

Just edited the post

It's difficult to understand exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but to change state based on a url navigation add a usePathname or useSearchParam hook and use the returned value in your useEffect.
After looking at your edit, I don't think your issue has anything to do with navigating. Event listeners can't access state after they were created. Use a ref for that, like this:

export default function TodoList() {

const initialTodos: { id: number, text: string }[] = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    initialTodos.push({
        id: i,
        text: "some fetched todos #" + (i + 1)
    });
}
const [dataState, _setState] = useState(initialTodos);
const data = useRef(dataState)
// If you don't want to remove the state altogether, use this as a drop in replacement for setting both state and the ref at the same time
const setState = (newState) => {
  _setState(newState)
   data.current = newState
}

const chunk = useRef(1) // Move chunk to a ref as well.

let onScroll = (event: Event) => {

// this event handler updates the state with random data after user scrolls down a bit 

    let vp = event.target as VisualViewport;
    let halfOfTheBlockheight = (148 * 30) / 2; //const
    let totalHeightOfTheBlock = 148 * 30 * chunk.number;
    let middleOfTheBlockPageTop = totalHeightOfTheBlock - halfOfTheBlockheight;
    if (vp.pageTop > middleOfTheBlockPageTop) {

// increment chunk's number so user needs to scroll lower to get a new data each time new data is fetched

        chunk.current = chunk.current + 1;
        let length = data.length;
        let arr = data.current; // Change this to use the ref now with '.current'
        for (let i = length; i < length + 30; i++) {
            arr.push({ id: i + 1, text: 'random' + i });
        }
        setState(arr);
    }
};

// No need to reset chunk now. It's being handled with the useRef hook. You can set it using the 'current' property if you need to, but it will be set to one on the first render.

useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll, false);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll) // This removes the event listener when the user navigates away from this component.
}, []); // You only want to set the event listener once


return (
    <>
        <Link href="/"> Base Route </Link>
        <Link href="/example"> Another Route </Link>
        <ul>
            {data.map((item: { id: number, text: string }) => (


The expected behavior is that it is possible to reset the state after the navigation in the first case, but it's not. I tried resetting the state in useEffect, but it didn't do anything. So, thanks for an advice about usePathname, but my problem is not about how to update the state, it's rather about that it is basically impossible to do after the navigation.

You need to be more clear about what exactly you're trying to accomplish. usePathname and useSearchParams run when they change... you know, when you navigate.

Well I tried it too, but it didn't help. All I want is to be able to update the state after navigation...

I've just updated the question, removing extra code, and adding some comments. I hope It made my problem clearer.

Ok, I just updated the answer.

Man, thanks a lot! That was it. All I had to do is to create function-in-the-middle to set the state and save it in useRef as well, and in the event handler use useRef data as source for setState and it started working as expected!!!  The use of useRef for chunk number's storage and the cleanup function in the useEffect to kill event handler are just great ideas! You've just saved me :) I would never think of this.

I'm curious, why do you want to implement an infinite scroll functionality yourself instead of using established libraries with many features? Personally, I'm using react-infinite-scroll-component with my nextjs app.
